# Does high LH means I have PCOS?

Tags: gynecology, female, ovulation

I have never heard about pcos until someone mentioned it to me last week. I am 28 years old and I had irregular periods (long cycles) in the last years and when I went to the doctor she did a hormonal test and found a high LH (but the other things were normal, including testerone). She told me to take mini pills then I told her I am trying to conceive, then she gave me duphaston ( I drink it during the second half of the cycle and since then my cycle become normal, 28 days)

Comment: Was the _someone_ who mentioned PCOS your doctor?

Comment: No it was a friend...

Comment: then I recommend asking your doctor about your LH values and PCOS.

Comment: I have an appointment next week and I will ask her. I am just a bit worried that's why I couldn't wait.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leutenising hormone (LH) can be elevated in a number of conditions, including polycystic ovarian syndrome (PCOS).

How PCOS develops is not fully understood, but there are three main processes going on that give rise to the possible [symptoms](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/polycystic-ovary-syndrome-pcos/symptoms/) of irregular periods and ovulation, excessive hair growth but with thinning scalp hair, weight gain and oily skin or acne.

These three processes are below, adapted from this [article](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/551015_2)):

1. An alteration in [gonadotropin-releasing hormone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonadotropin-releasing_hormone) secretion results in increased luteinizing hormone (LH) secretion. This is what can affect the normal [menstrual cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_cycle) and ovulation.
2. An alteration in insulin secretion and insulin action results in hyperinsulinemia and [insulin resistance](https://www.diabetes.co.uk/insulin-resistance.html). This is associated with weight gain and a higher risk of diabetes.
3. A defect in androgen synthesis that results in increased ovarian androgen production. This refers to testosterone, which is what causes symptoms of excess hair growth and oily skin.

While a high LH can be associated with PCOS, one might expect testosterone levels to be raised (though there are different ways to measure this and it can need some interpretation). Not all women experience all of the symptoms, and there is great variation in severity. The next step would usually be an ultrasound scan of the ovaries to look for multiple cysts.

There are [diagnostic criteria](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/18950759/) from the AE-PCOS Society (2009), which I have simplified a little here:

- Elevated testosterone *plus either*:
- Fewer than 6-9 periods per year (oligomenorrhoea) *or*
- At least 12 cysts in ovaries on ultrasound scan

---

By the way, welcome to the Health Stack Exchange. Personal medical questions are off-topic and no answers or comments on the site should be considered as medical advice. I have provided an answer discussing LH and PCOS in general terms. Be sure to keep in touch with your doctor.